# How to read from a .dat file that contains strings and doubles and write the doubles on a matrix?

Tags: c, file

I have a file that contains the following structure:

```
Caso Escp P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P5+ Caos HCaos
Total 0.099601 82.921184 1.459357 1.576886 0.381672 0.250597 0.392030 12.918674 0.000000
Biest 0.199601 65.802794 2.895808 3.160080 0.764870 0.502196 0.785629 25.889022 0.000000
Monoest 0.000000 99.971372 0.028628 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

As you can see, it has strings and doubles in the same file. I'm trying to get those doubles and write it in a matrix and print it on the screen. I already can do that with files that only contains doubles inside, however in this case I did not find a solution yet.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
#define lin 4
#define col 10
double N = 0.3;
char filename_porc[64], str[100];

int main()
{
    double mat[lin][col];       

    for (int k = 1; k < lin; k++)
    {
        for (int m = 1; m < col; m++)
        {
            printf("%f ", mat[k][m]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    sprintf(filename_porc, "(N = %g) resp.dat", N); 
    input_result = fopen(filename_porc, "r");

    printf("\n\n");

    fgets(str, 100, input_result);
    for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if ((i > 0) && (j > 0))
            {
                fscanf(input_result, "%g", &mat[i-1][j-1]);
                printf("%g ", mat[i-1][j-1]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(input_result);
    printf("\n *** End of Execution ***");
    getchar();
}
```

EDIT:

```
fgets(str, 100, input_result);

    for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0) { fscanf(input_result, "%s", str); }

            if ((i > 0) && (j > 0))
            {
                fscanf(input_result, "%g", &mat[i-1][j-1]);
                printf("%g ", mat[i-1][j-1]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: @ggorlen sorry to mix the structures. Actually I prefer to use C, so I edited the code to stay coherent.

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, you can read a single number like this:

```
fscanf(input_result, "%g", &x);
```

If you want to read two numbers with one command, you can do this:

```
fscanf(input_result, "%g %g", &x, &y);
```

To read a string followed by a number:

```
char str[20];
fscanf(input_result, "%s %g", str, &x);
```

(Note that "str" has no ampersand, because it's an array.)

So to read a string followed by several numbers, you could specify all of them:

```
fscanf(input_result, "%s %g %g %g %g %g", str, &arr[0], &arr[1], &arr[2],...
```

Or you could use a loop:

```
fscanf(input_result, "%s", str);
for(unsigned int k=0; k<col; ++k)
    fscanf(input_result, "%g", &arr[k]);
```

**EDIT:**
To read the entire first line, make sure `str` is big enough, and use `fgets`:

```
char str[100];
fgets( str, 100, input_result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I get only the numbers from my file? because i'm trying to to the way you said but the problem remais. I cannot manage to skip the entire first line of strings to start reading the second one and apply this:





`fscanf(input_result, "%s", str);
for(unsigned int k=0; k<col; ++k)
    fscanf(input_result, "%g", &mat[k]);`

Comment: I've modified the code as you instructed and updated the code on the question box, however the output on the screen continues to show a list of zeros in the matrix. For some reason it did not take the values in the .dat file and wrote in the matrix. :(

Comment: @Lug: what happens when you print the first line, to verify that you read it correctly? What happens when you try to read the numbers from the second line into a simple array (`double[col]`)?

Comment: The thing is that in the second, third and fourth lines it still have one string element before all the numbers. To work around the problem I did what i'm showing in the EDITED part of the question that I updated now. But it still showing only zeros in the screen.

Comment: Tried to print only in a simple matrix `double[col]'. Still the same problem

Comment: @Lug: I'm sorry, I made a typo in my answer; I'll correct it. But you tried to implement my approach without understanding it, which is almost impossible.

Answer (score 0):

When reading a file, it's pretty restrictive to [hardcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) the number of rows, columns and buffers. Here's a more flexible approach using [dynamic memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).

It's not without assumptions about the input file, though: the file should end in a newline, have fixed columns, no formatting errors, first row is headers, etc. It also makes frequent calls to `realloc`, which in practice shouldn't result in many system calls but could be sped up by doubling capacity rather than incrementing it. Consider this a proof of concept.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct matrix {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    double **data;
} matrix;

int main() {
    matrix m = {0, 0, 0};
    m.data = malloc(sizeof(double *));
    int digit_buf_len = 0;
    char digit_buf[32];
    FILE *fin = fopen("resp.dat", "r");
    int c;

    // skip the first row
    while ((c = fgetc(fin)) != EOF && c != '\n');

    for (int col = 0; (c = fgetc(fin)) != EOF;) {
        if (isdigit(c) || c == '.') {
            digit_buf[digit_buf_len++] = c;
        }
        else if (digit_buf_len) {
            if (col) {
                m.data[m.rows] = realloc(m.data[m.rows], 
                                         (col + 1) * sizeof(double));
            }
            else {
                m.data = realloc(m.data, (m.rows + 1) * sizeof(double *));
                m.data[m.rows] = malloc(sizeof(double));
            }

            digit_buf[digit_buf_len] = '\0';
            sscanf(digit_buf, "%lf", &m.data[m.rows][col]);
            memset(digit_buf, 0, digit_buf_len);
            digit_buf_len = 0;
            col++;
        }

        if (c == '\n') {
            m.cols = m.cols > col ? m.cols : col;
            m.rows++;
            col = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.cols; j++) {
            printf("%f ", m.data[i][j]);
        }

        free(m.data[i]);
        puts("");
    }

    free(m.data);
    fclose(fin);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0.099601 82.921184 1.459357 1.576886 0.381672 0.250597 0.392030 12.918674 0.000000
0.199601 65.802794 2.895808 3.160080 0.764870 0.502196 0.785629 25.889022 0.000000
0.000000 99.971372 0.028628 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

If the file changed to:

```
Caso Escp P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P5+ Caos HCaos
Total 0.099601 82.921184 1.459357 1.576886
Biest 0.199601 65.802794 2.895808 3.160080
Mxxxxst 1.000000 99.971372 1.028628 2.000000
Mxxxxst 2.000000 19.971372 7.028628 3.000000
Mxxxxst 3.000000 29.971372 6.028628 5.000000
Mxxxxst 4.000000 29.971372 3.028628 6.000000
```

then it still works:

```
0.099601 82.921184 1.459357 1.576886
0.199601 65.802794 2.895808 3.160080
1.000000 99.971372 1.028628 2.000000
2.000000 19.971372 7.028628 3.000000
3.000000 29.971372 6.028628 5.000000
4.000000 29.971372 3.028628 6.000000
```